# What is the best practice for deploying changes to SAP BusinessObjects reports?

Tags: deployment, business-objects

What is the best practice for deploying changes to SAP BusinessObjects reports? Can they be deployed from a Development to a Production Environment via a command line operation? The Wizard approach seems prone to mistakes.

Answer (score 1):

The wizard approach is not error prone. Its true that even if the report is deployed without any errors, it pops up an error. You just need to ignore that. Something SAP BO team should work on.

Command Line, as far as I know can be achievable using the JAVA SDK. Also read the documentation of the Version Manager once, which you are using for deployment.